# How can I pass a property of a class as a parameter of a method in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, selector, key-value-coding

How can I pass a property of a class as a parameter of a method in objective-c?

So as an example assume I have:

- a CoreData managed object class MyData with dynamic properties PropA, PropB, PropC all of the same type
- I have a utils method that will perform calculations and update one of these properties, which takes as input the MyData instance
- how can I arrange so the utils method can accept an indication of which property to use in the calculations and updating?  (e.g. PropB)

So then need:

1. A way to pass an indication of the property to the method (e.g. send as String?)
2. A way in the method to take this (from 1 above) and use this to both (a) access the value of this property in the MyData instance the method has, PLUS (b) update the property too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A properties will have setter and getter method. In you case, I assume there are setPropA, setPropB, setPropC for setters and PropA, PropB, PropC for getters.

Then I pass string "PropA" to util, indicate I want to access property named PropA.
The util can get the value by

```
id val = [aObj performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"PropA")];
```

And set the property by

```
[aObj performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"SetPropA") withObject:newValue];
```

Or, You can pass setter and getter as parameter by `NSStringFromSelector()`, turn selector into a NSString. For example, I pass setter and getter by NSDictionary.

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          NSStringFromSelector(@selector(setPropA:)), kSetterKey,
                          NSStringFromSelector(@selector(PropA)), kGetterKey, nil];

// inside myUtil
NSString *setter = [userInfo objectForKey:kSetterKey];
[aObj performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(setter) withObject:newValue];
NSString *getter = [userInfo objectForKey:kGetterKey];
id val = [aObj performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(getter)];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Toro - just wondering what the advantage would be of using this selector method? The valueForKey method Jorn suggested seems simpler at face value no?

Comment: As far as I know, in iOS not every thing conforms to NSKeyValueCoding protocol for KVO. NSObject and UIView don't conform to that procotol.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can pass the property name as a String.

Then you can access the indicated property via Key-Value Coding:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html

Example:

```
- (void) myUtilMethod: (MyData *) myData
     forPropertyNamed: (NSString *) propName /* which property to operate on (1) */
{
   id oldValue = [ myData valueForKey: propName]; // get value (2a)

   id newValue = ...; // your calculation here

   [myData setValue: newValue forKey: propName]; // set value (2b)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't bind the 2 classes directly. You should set up a pattern design that allows you to loosely couple them together by creating a class that will do the interface between those two.